# Combine input and select input/change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields and two select fields.

I do some frontend validation on input of the input fields and when I change the select of the select fields ... for ALL fields.

The only way I get this to work is if I split it like this:

```
var is_currencyBilling;
var is_countryBilling;
var is_cityBilling;
var is_postalBilling;

$('#cityBilling,#postalBilling').on('input', function () {

    ...

}); 

$('#currencyBilling,#countryBilling').on('change', function () {

    ...

});
```

Is there any way to combine this? Or do I have to split it like above?

Edit:

If I combine it in a change like this:

```
$('#cityBilling,#postalBilling,#currencyBilling,#countryBilling').on('change', function () {

    console.log('Test');

    ...

});
```

... it works after I tab to another input field or a input field looses focus. But is there any chance to keep the former validation behaviour right when I 'change' the value of an input field?

Comment: you can use change for input field too

Comment: both text inputs and select inputs support the `change` event

Comment: change is the way to gooo

Comment: I combined them in a 'change' (see Edit above) .. yet, if I now change a input field ... it ignores the change. What might causes this? I don't even get a console 'Test'

Comment: For text inputs, I believe the change event is only triggered when you leave focus of the input. Are you tabbing after the change or clicking a new input?  @PhilippM

Comment: @bassxzero . Yes you are right. Now I have that behavior. Yet what is missing is ... is there any chance to also keep the behaviour right when I change the value of an input field ...  ?

Comment: Are you trying to do the same thing for both types of inputs or are you trying to lessen the selectors when binding?

Comment: I want to trigger the event (validation) right on change of the select ... and when I change values in the input fields ... for all fields

Comment: So you want to do run the same code for both inputs then? Why don't you just make a function and call it for both inputs events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use same change event for all or use multiple events like `$(selectors).on('change input', validate)`

But you can also listen for different events that use the same *event handler*.

Within that handler your business logic can adapt to the event type or element type or whatever other special conditions you need

Basic example

```js
$('input:text').on('input', validate);
$('input:checkbox').on('click', validate)
$('select').on('change', validate);

function validate(evt) {
  console.clear()
  var $el = $(this),
    val = $el.val();

  console.log(evt.type + ' event on: ' + this.name + ', new value is: ', val);

  if ($el.is('input:text')) {
    console.log('This is an input:text');
    
  } else if ($el.is('select')) {
    console.log('This is a select');
    
  }else if ($el.is('input:checkbox')) {
    console.log('Checkbox is checked = ', this.checked)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Inp1: <input name="input_one" type="text" /> Inp2: <input name="input_two" type="text" /> <br><br> 
Check<input name="check_one" value="one" type="checkbox">
<br><br> 

Sel 1
<select name="sel_one">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>

Sel 2
<select name="sel_two">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```